# Test class code coverage - Syncing custom fields between quotes and opportunities (Custom Quote Sync)

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, quotelineitem

I have copied the code from the blog [amitsalesforce](http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.in/2014/11/syncing-custom-fields-between-quotes.html) for syncing custom fields from Opportunity Line Item to Quote Line Item on creation of Quote.

Made small changes in that code and that works fine for me. But when it comes to test class I get only code coverage of 70%. Below is the test class

```
@isTest

public with sharing class testTriggerOLISyncQLI{
    static testMethod void myUnitTriggerOLISyncQLI(){

        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Camphell');
        a.AccountNumber = '2345';
        a.SAP_SYNCED__c = true;
        a.BillingStreet = 'Oliver Mart st';
        a.BillingCity =  'Tasborn';
        a.BillingState = 'Newyork';
        a.BillingCountry = 'US';
        insert a;

        Account_Sales_Area__c ASA = new Account_Sales_Area__c();
        ASA.SAP_ACC_ID__c = a.id;
        ASA.SAP_VKORG__c = '3000';
        ASA.SAP_VTWEG__c = '10';
        ASA.SAP_SPART__c = '00';
        ASA.SAP_INCO1__c = 'FOF';
        ASA.SAP_INCO2__c = 'Sample';
        ASA.SAP_ZTERM__c = 'Rs';
        ASA.SAP_PARVW__c = 'SHIP';
        insert ASA;

        PriceBook2 PB = new PriceBook2();
        PB.Name = 'Standard';
        PB.Condition_Type__c = 'SLG1';
        insert PB;



        Product2 p = new product2(name='unittest');
        p.Family = 'License';
        p.SAP_MATNR__c = 'M-003';
        p.ProductCode = 'M-003';
        p.isActive = true;
        p.SAP_SYNCED__c = true;
        insert p;

        Customer_Material_Info__c CMI = new Customer_Material_Info__c();
        CMI.SAP_ACC_ID__c = a.id;
        CMI.SAP_PROD_ID__c = p.id;
        CMI.SAP_KDMAT__c = '4325';
        CMI.SAP_POSTX__c = 'CMI test Product';
        insert CMI;


        //Pricebook2 stdPb = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true limit 1];
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = pricebookId ,
                product2id = p.id,
                unitprice=40.0,
                isActive=true);
        insert pbe;

        Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2014, 10, 01);
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name ='Camphell Opp');
        opp.AccountId = a.id;
        opp.StageName = 'Sample Request';
        opp.CloseDate = myDate ;
        opp.PriceBook2Id = pricebookId ;
        insert opp;
        System.debug('Oppprice>>>' +opp.PriceBook2Id);

        List<OpportunityLineItem >oli = new List <OpportunityLineItem >();

        oli.add( new OpportunityLineItem(PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id,
                OpportunityId=opp.Id,
                Quantity=10,
                Customer_Material_Number__c = '6745',
                Distribution_Channel__c = '10',
                Division__c = '00',
                Sales_Org__c = '3000',
                SAP_Customer_Price__c = 35,
                TotalPrice=100));                                                       
        oli.add( new OpportunityLineItem(PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id,
                OpportunityId=opp.Id,
                Quantity=9,
                Customer_Material_Number__c = '6790',
                Distribution_Channel__c = '111',
                Division__c = '01',
                Sales_Org__c = '3500',
                SAP_Customer_Price__c = 37,
                TotalPrice=100));    

        insert oli;  

        Quote q = new Quote(Name = 'Camphell Quote');
        q.OpportunityId = opp.id;
        q.PriceBook2Id = pricebookId ;  
        insert q;


        List<QuoteLineItem > qli = new List<QuoteLineItem > ();

        qli.add( new QuoteLineItem(pricebookentryid =pbe.Id,
                QuoteId=q.Id,
                Quantity=10,
                unitprice=123,
                Distribution_Channel__c = '10',
                Division__c = '00',
                Sales_Org__c = '3000',
                SAP_Customer_Price__c = 37
                ));
        qli.add( new QuoteLineItem(pricebookentryid =pbe.Id,
                QuoteId=q.Id,
                Quantity=10,
                unitprice=111,
                Distribution_Channel__c = '11',
                Division__c = '01',
                Sales_Org__c = '3001',
                SAP_Customer_Price__c = 35
                ));  

        insert qli;    
    }
}
```

**The code didnt cover this part**

[image]

Where am I missing ?? Suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the blog, it updates and syncs the QLIs when the OLIs change. Your test class simply inserts a single oli and qli without ever updating either one of them. That's why the rest of the lines are never covered.

Also, you'll want to use `testStartTest` before you do your DML for oli and qli and then `testStopTest` when you're finished. Don't forget to add assertions to your test class to show that the changes made by the trigger were as expected.